# React: stale props in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Here is the CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/stale-prop-one-g92sv?file=/src/App.js

I find the child components will not show the correct counter values after two button clicks, though the counter is actually incrementing:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const [counter] = useState(value);
  return <span>{counter}</span>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const isVisible = counter !== 1;
  console.log(counter);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1)}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
      {isVisible && (
        <div>
          Message 1 is: <MyComponent value={counter} />
        </div>
      )}
      <div style={isVisible ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}>
        Message 2 is: <MyComponent value={counter} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I try to force child component re-render by assigning counter to its key:

```
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const isVisible = counter !== 1;
  console.log(counter);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1)}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
      {isVisible && (
        <div>
          Message 1 is: <MyComponent  key = {counter} value={counter} />
        </div>
      )}
      <div style={isVisible ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}>
        Message 2 is: <MyComponent key = {counter} value={counter} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It works, but I still have no idea why the previous one does not work, since the `props.value` in `MyComponent` has changed...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this:

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const [counter] = useState(value);
  return <span>{counter}</span>;
};
```

You're telling React to set the initial state to the first `value` prop passed to the component, on mount.

When the component re-renders, the component has already been mounted, so the value passed to `useState` is ignored - instead, the `counter` in that child is taken from *the state of `MyComponent`* - which is equal to the initial state in `MyComponent`, the initial `value` prop passed.

For what you're trying to do, you only have a single value throughout the app here that you want to use everywhere, so you should only have one `useState` call, in the parent - and then render the counter in the child from the prop, which will change with the parent state.

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  return <span>{value}</span>;
};
```

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, thanks for the informative answer. Accordingly, during re-render, React will assume that the state is the same as before since the child component cannot go up to check parent component's state?

Comment: Here, for the child, React will return the state of the child from `useState`. The child's state never changes, because the child state setter is never called, so the `counter` stays at its initial value.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I still dont get it. Isnt React re-renders component when props change?

Comment: @asdasd Yes, the component is getting re-rendered, but in the original code, the value that gets printed to the screen during re-rendering is taken from the *state of the child component* instead of from the *prop of the parent component*, which get out of sync.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for answer! I guess this related to how reconciliation & diffing process works to understand if re-render is needed, right?